# How to pass cin or ifstream object as argument function

Tags: c++

I though this would work since `ifstream` inherits from `istream`

```
string getFileContents(istream& file_contents)
{
    string result;

    string line;
    while (getline(file_contents, line))
        result += line + "\n";

    return result;
}
```

then I want to call this function like so:

```
ifstream file_input;
getFileContents(file_input);
...
getFileContents(cin);
```

but I get this error in visual studio:

'getFileContents' : cannot convert parameter 1 from `std::istream` to `std::ifstream &`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should work; are you sure you didn't leave around a wrong prototype that has a parameter of type `ifstream &` instead of `istream &`?

Comment: @ladookie: it's a classic error, I saw it so many times that now I spot it "on the fly" `:)` BTW, if my answer solved your problem you can mark it as accepted (thank you :) ).

Comment: new to c++, why does it do this

Comment: if object type is ifstream, why does it get passed isteram

Comment: Because ifstream derives from istream.